# check null or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table in my database, and i need to add 1 each time. unless if it's null I want to set it to one. I've thought of make the default value zero, but i need the zero too.

for example

```
-----------------------
id      number
-----------------------
01       NULL   
02        3
03        1
```

i don't want to run 2 queries.

```
QUERY1 : SELECT number and store it in variable

if($number == NULL) $number = 1
else
{
$number = $number++
}

QUERY2 : UPDATE number
```

is there any 1 SQL Query can do this for me without process the data in php ?

thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET number=IF(number IS NULL,1,number+1)
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can detect whether a value is `NULL` or not. Do this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET number = IF(ISNULL(number), 1, number+1)
```

This will set any number that's `NULL` to 1, and increase the other numbers by one. So this:

```
-----------------------
id      number
-----------------------
01       NULL   
02        3
03        1
```

will yield:

```
-----------------------
id      number
-----------------------
01        1 
02        4
03        2
```

This way, you don't have to go through PHP anymore.